# How to replace all zeros in numpy matrix with corresponding values from another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For example

```
a = np.matrix('1 0; 0 4')
b = mp.matrix('13 17;19 23')
```

By performing what operations will I get:

```
c = [[1 17]
     [19 4]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logical indexing:

```
d = (a==0)
a[d] = b[d]
```

`d` is an array of truth values the same size as `a` or `b` which can be used as a mask. Only the elements marked as `True` in `d` are regarded in the assignment operation. If you need a separate array with the result,

```
d = (a==0)
c = a.copy()
c[d] = b[d]
```

A good way is to use `numpy.where()`, as pointed out by Anton:

```
c = numpy.where(a == 0, b, a)
```

Note that this is nearly equivalent to the three-line version above because the expression `a == 0` actually creates a mask array like `d`, then passes it to `where`.

Both methods have advantages and disadvantages. If you are doing the transformation in-place (e.g. fixing zeros in a matrix), the first option is best. If you are doing the computation only once, Anton's method is best. If you are going to use the same mask many times, it is better to separate the mask computation from the application of `where`:

```
d = (a == 0)
c = numpy.where(d, a, b)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
c = np.where(a==0, b, a)

In [15]: c
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1, 17],
       [19,  4]])
```

Comment: Didn't know about `where`, thanks. Also good job on writing my 3-liner inn one line :-)